# How could I update certain text in a giant list?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a script that updates the rating value for each of these plugins (example list, the one I would use is giant). I would input them all in at once. Its markdown file text

```
- [zHack Lite](https://polymart.org/resource/460)  
Version: 1.8.8  
Rating: ???  
Currently Active
- [ZK Anticheat](https://github.com/Valou447/ZK-ANTICHEAT)  
Version: ???  
Rating: ???  
Discontinued
- [3d Angle Attack](https://www.spigotmc.org/resources/85021)  
Version: 1.7 - 1.16  
Rating: 3  
Currently Active
- [8bAC](https://www.spigotmc.org/resources/47577/)  
Version: 1.12  
Rating: 2.917  
Discontinued
```

Would it be possible?
I use the https://spiget.org/ api to get the rating values

Im thinking I would have to somehow get the id/url from the link and use the api to get the new values then somehow replace only the value in the section below the link I got the id/url from

I have tried getting all the links in the list then looping through them and getting the new values from the api but I couldn't figure out how to replace the old value with them

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Please provice a [mcve]

Comment: Nico Haase I have tried something with getting all the links in the list then looping through them and getting the new values from the api but I couldn't figure out how to replace the old value with them

Comment: "I have tried something" - then add it to your question by editing

Comment: I did that 10 minutes ago or so

Comment: Did you? And why has that vanished again? I don't see any JS code in the question, so maybe you could add it again, along with your attempts to resolve the problem?

Comment: @JustDoom Add the code you used, not the list. We can't possibly know where exactly you are stuck if you don't post your code.

Comment: @bluevulture Im more stuck at, I dont know how to even start doing this more than, How do I continue doing this. my attempts barely even got past 1 line

Comment: I might have an idea, if I split them all up at every "- [" so they are all in their own string I can then get the id, fetch the api then get the value of rating and somehow replace it

Comment: Please share your attempts. Otherwise, other people can not see **where** you are going wrong, and such they cannot provide help

Comment: I will, I didnt really have any code to show before as I was stuck on where to even start mostly